# strscp loop forever when when the value is copied direcly from the buffer

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

## Problem

I am learning Linux kernel module development and trying to understand why the strscp loops infinitely when value in buffer is copied.

## Code

```
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/miscdevice.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/string.h>

#define LEN 13
#define ID "ABCDEF2103a5"
static  char buffer[LEN];

static ssize_t hello_write(struct file *file,
        const char *buf, size_t count,
        loff_t *ppos)
{
    
    ssize_t len;
    
    if (count != LEN)
        return -EINVAL;
    
    // This loops forever when 0 returned!
    strscpy(buffer, buf, LEN);
    
    return len;
}


static const struct file_operations file_ops = {
    .owner  = THIS_MODULE,
    .write  = hello_write,
};

static struct miscdevice misc_dev = {
    MISC_DYNAMIC_MINOR,
    "check",
    &file_ops
};
```

When the value "ABCDEF2103a5" (or anything of same length) is passed to the module via `echo ABCDEF2103a5 > /dev/check`, it just prints the value continuously.

Below is the output from `dmesg -wH`:

```
[  +0.000002] ABCDEF2103a5
[  +0.000003] ABCDEF2103a5
[  +0.000003] ABCDEF2103a5
[  +0.000002] ABCDEF2103a5
[  +0.000003] ABCDEF2103a5
[  +0.000002] ABCDEF2103a5
[  +0.000003] ABCDEF2103a5
[  +0.000002] ABCDEF2103a5
[  +0.000003] ABCDEF2103a5
[  +0.000003] ABCDEF2103a5
[  +0.000002] ABCDEF2103a5
[  +0.000008] ABCDEF2103a5
```

It occupies CPU 100%. To make it stop, I had to find the PID of the shell and kill it.

When 0 is returned (len is assigned 0 or `return 0`), there is nothing printed and bash hangs.

When other values (other than 0) are returned, `bash: echo: write error:...` some form of error message is thrown but it does not hang.

**What value should be returned?** We cannot just do `return;`.

## Works Fine

Complete functional code where at first the buffer is copied to a temporary array, which is then copied to global variable.

```
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/miscdevice.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/string.h>

#define LEN 13
#define ID "ABCDEF2103a5"
static  char buffer[LEN];

static ssize_t hello_write(struct file *file,
        const char *buf, size_t count,
        loff_t *ppos)
{
    ssize_t len;
    char *msg = kmalloc (count + 1, GFP_KERNEL);

    if (!msg)
        return -ENOMEM;

    if (count != LEN)
        return -EINVAL;

    len = simple_write_to_buffer(msg, count, ppos, buf,
      count);

    if ( strncmp(msg, ID, LEN-1 ) != 0 )
      return -EINVAL;
    
    // Copied from the temporary variable
    // which works fine.
    strscpy(buffer, msg, LEN);

    return len;
}


static const struct file_operations file_ops = {
    .owner  = THIS_MODULE,
    .write  = hello_write,
};

static struct miscdevice misc_dev = {
    MISC_DYNAMIC_MINOR,
    "check",
    &file_ops
};
```

Commented section from above are un-commented. Here, the buffer is copied to a temp variable first. And the value from the temp variable is copied using `strscpy` which works fine.

Comment: When you say "loops forever", how do you know it's looping forever? Or do you just mean it stalls?

Comment: What are `buffer` and `LEN` and where are they defined?

Comment: @wxz The programs prints the value continuously and the system hangs.

Comment: @stark These information are added. Thanks.

Comment: `buf` points to the memory passed to the `write` system call. Regular functions (like `strscpy` shouldn't be used for **user-space** pointers. Instead, firstly copy the user data into kernel space using `copy_from_user`, and then work with the copied data.

Comment: As for the looping, you declare `ssize_t len` variable but have never initialized it. Probably, it is 0, so your `write` method always returns 0, which is interpreted by the user space as "no bytes has been written" and user part repeats the writing again and again.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Your explanation makes sense. But even returning some value has issues, throws some error message. Question asked on what should be the value returned?

Comment: `write` method should return the number of bytes in `buf` which has been **processed**. If there are unprocessed bytes then `write` could be repeated with that bytes. The meaning of "processed" is up to you. E.g. if you assume that you have processed all bytes, then return value of `count` parameter.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - You are right. But what ever number (including positive) is returned, it is related with some error value and hence error message.

Comment: "But what ever number (including positive) is returned, it is related with some error value and hence error message." - No, positive return value is not related with the error code. If this is your case, then update the question post with the exact code which cause it. And make sure to fix the problem stated in [my other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68198878/strscp-loop-forever-when-when-the-value-is-copied-direcly-from-the-buffer?noredirect=1#comment120533242_68198878) about passing user-space pointer to .`strscpy`.

Comment: BTW, if you wonder how `simple_write_to_buffer` works, then you could look into its [implementation](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.47/source/fs/libfs.c#L752), it is quite simple.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Noted your point on the issue with the returned value. I will update the answer for this question and create that as a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the correct answer is commented by @Tsyvarev.

"As for the looping, you declare ssize_t len variable but have never initialized it. Probably, it is 0, so your write method always returns 0, which is interpreted by the user space as "no bytes has been written" and user part repeats the writing again and again."

And the refactored code is:

```
static ssize_t hello_write(struct file *file,
        const char *buf, size_t count,
        loff_t *ppos)
{

    ssize_t len;
    ssize_t copy_len;
    char *msg = kmalloc(count + 1, GFP_KERNEL);

    if (!msg)
        return -ENOMEM;

    if (count != LEN)
        goto einval;

    len = simple_write_to_buffer(msg, count, ppos,
            buf, count);

    if (len <= 0) {
        kfree(msg);
        return len;
    }

    if (strncmp(msg, ID, LEN-1) != 0)
        goto einval;

    copy_len = strscpy(buffer, strim(msg), LEN);

    if (copy_len < 0) {
        kfree(msg);
        return copy_len;
    }

    return len;

einval:
    kfree(msg);
    return -EINVAL;
}
```